# The equivalent circuit for \$V_{in} > 0\$ with the amplitude of \$V_{out}\$

Tags: diodes

I have a strong mathematical background and I am trying to improve my (poor) physics.
If this is not the right stackexchange forum for this subject, I would be grateful if you could refer me to the right one.

I have created the following electrical circuit:
[image]

I am trying to calculate and draw the following things:

1. The equivalent circuit for \$V_{in} > 0\$, giving the amplitude of \$V_{out}\$.
2. The equivalent circuit for \$V_{in} < 0\$, giving the amplitude of \$V_{out}\$.
3. The signal \$V_{out}\$ as a function of time, for a full cycle of the input signal.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that those are "ideal" diodes? What have you tried so far?

Comment: "The equivalent circuit for Vin"? - it is what you want it to be.